# Pass a simple integer to a thread’s start function at thread creation time

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

The code is sample, what I need to do is to modify.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <pthread.h>

void  *my_function (void*); // Function for the thread 

int main ()
{
    pthread_t   my_thread ; // Declare a thread identifier
    int  rc1, x = 7; 

    // Create my_thread 
    if ( (rc1 = pthread_create (& my_thread, NULL,  & my_function,  (void*) &x)))
    {
        printf ("Error in creating thread %d\n", rc1);
    }

    pthread_join ( my_thread, NULL); // wait for thread to exit

    return (0); // exit the main function
}


// The my_thread is created with my_function() which accepts an argument 
void  *my_function(void* arg)
{
    int i = *(int*)arg;

    printf ("The argument which this thread received is %d \n", i ) ; 

    pthread_exit (NULL) ;    // thread exits
}
```

The question is: Pass a simple integer to a thread’s start function at thread creation time. But I don't know how to pass a simple integer to a thread's start function, and I also don't know what is thread creation time.

Comment: Thread creation time is when you call `pthread_create()`. This may surprise you, given the name, but there you have it. Currently you are passing a pointer to an integer to the thread, which is somewhat more clean than passing an integer directly.

Comment: @EOF While passing an `int` by reference as posted in the question is cleaner, that does mean the thread calling `pthread_create` has to preserve the value of the variable passed until some communication is received from the new thread that it's safe to either change the value or destroy the variable.  For example, a `for` loop that starts `N` threads where each thread is passed its "id" - `0` through `N - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

If your imlementation has `intptr_t` (most of them do), you can modify the code as following:

```
int  rc1; 
intptr_t x = 7
...
pthread_create (&my_thread, NULL, &my_function, (void*)x));
...
void* my_function(void* arg)
{
    intptr_t i = (intptr_t)arg;
...
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the guarantee about `[u]intptr_t` is that you can round-trip a `void*` through a `[u]intptr_t`, not the other way around: `void* -> [u]intptr_t -> void*` produces a pointer that compares equal to the initial pointer, but `[u]intptr_t -> void* -> [u]intptr_t` does not guarantee equality of the `[u]intptr_t`s.

Comment: @EOF, I thought about it too. But I can't see how it is even theoretically possible that void -> ptr -> void is valid, but ptr->void->ptr is not. Basic transitivity (I guess it's a right word) demands it. Alright, absent compilers which do the transformation above through sort of lookup tables.

Comment: It's actually very simple: Imagine an architecture where pointers are 32 bits, and integers (including `[u]intptr_t`) are 64 bits. Now any pointer converted to `[u]intptr_t` can obviously be converted *back*, but an arbitrary `[u]intptr_t` cannot be converted back from `void*`.

Comment: Yes, somehow this simple fact didn't occur to me. I guess, downvote is deserved. However, the downvoter could explain the reasons.